# Swift: UIScrollView/UITextView jumps up when entering text

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm using a UITextView inside a UIView that's inside a UIScrollView. Whenever I launch the app for the first time and attempt to type something into the UITextView, the view jumps up.
Also, when the view is first visible, the textview is not completely visible.

I've attempted to pin the UIView to the top layout guide. It stops that issue from occurring, however when a large body of text is entered in the UITextView, I'm unable to scroll down to view the song thumbnail.

What could be done to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Are you move up your view while keyboard appear?

Comment: @JD. I'm not moving the view up when the keyboard is visible.

Comment: may be because of you have added media assets in your textview.

Comment: the image view is outside the textview, in the uiview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wasn't necessarily the fix I wanted, but I realised UIScrollView is sometimes a little tricky to overcome.

I removed the UIView that held the UITextView and the album image and placed them directly into the UIScrollView. Then clipped the bottom of the UIScrollView to the bottom layout guide.

This stopped the jitter issue when typing but it's still not perfect.